# Xamarin Open UWP Open file from "Documents" library

Tags: xamarin.forms, uwp

I have a Xamarin UWP app and am trying to load a file from my current users "Documents" library.

I understand that I need to add a File Type Association declaration first.  I've done this and the file icon has changed to my application icon.

In the app I'm then using the FilePicker plugin from here...

https://github.com/ArtjomP/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

```
        FileData file = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
        Byte[] data = file.DataArray;
```

All I do is browse to the file and select it, but the application crashes with an access violation on the second line.

I've added the following capabilities to my UWP manifest, not sure if they are event relevant anymore.

```
<uap:Capability Name="documentsLibrary" />
<uap:Capability Name="removableStorage" />
```

How do I open my files?  I ideally need to use a convenient location like the documents library.

Nick.

Edit:

I've followed this article, and still no joy.

https://www.pmichaels.net/2016/11/11/uwp-accessing-documents-library/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a old package which most likely is no longer supported.

Try this one, https://github.com/jfversluis/FilePicker-Plugin-for-Xamarin-and-Windows

It is quite simple, and also supports UWP.

Sample usage

```
try
        {
            FileData fileData = await CrossFilePicker.Current.PickFile();
            if (fileData == null)
                return; // user canceled file picking

            string fileName = fileData.FileName;
            string contents = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(fileData.DataArray);

            System.Console.WriteLine("File name chosen: " + fileName);
            System.Console.WriteLine("File data: " + contents);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            System.Console.WriteLine("Exception choosing file: " + ex.ToString());
        }
```

Comment: Have you any idea on how Windows manages permissions to this file?  It seems to only give me access to the file, on the call stack that invoked the picker, for that one file, for a brief period of time.  Then it revokes access.  That's going to force me to have to create a copy of the file in my apps storage area.

Surely Windows hasn't gone this far backwards and I must be doing something wrong?  It works fine in Android, allowing me repeat access to the file, even after restarting the app.

Comment: @Nick this is UWP.  UWP apps are sandboxed.

Comment: Yup, I'm aware of that, it really limits what you can do with an app if you can't store data files in a folder that's in the users documents library.  I guess they are pushing for people using OneDrive to store the files, unless I'm missing something here?

Comment: One such feature would be a recently opened documents list, is that even possible with UWP?

Comment: I've just used a UWP app that does exactly what I want to do.  Open a file in documents folder of a specific extension, and then open it again in the future without requiring the user goes through a file picker.  So I'm pretty sure this is possible within the context of the sandbox.  I'm suspecting it's the extension, I will have to do more research before I can confirm this.

Comment: Actually, to clarify, it's not the extension, I'm being stupid, it's my code for opening the file outside of the filepicker callstack.  I was using File.ReadAllBytes, this doesn't work, using the StorageFile mechanism does.  Still, this extension works where the previous one failed so I'm all good there.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I reworded the answer for clarity, and to avoid some implications that @MickyD rightly pointed in comments and I don't agree with those implications either:

This seems like a bug in the package as it doesn't work according to its documentation and one possible thing to do is to submit the issue to GitHub so that the bug is resolved by the developer of the package.

The other possible thing to do is to look for the alternatives. You may try to find other similar packages and see if they work, and the alternative for which I am sure that works is to use the native functions in `System.Windows.Storage` (as it is officially supported).

Comment: Because you are essentially saying _”if your program ever has a bug it must be that pesky nuget package with xxxx downloads or less”_.   Such a philosophy is harmful to the advance of new packages and not accurate for cliche markets that will ever have greater than xxxx downloads

Comment: I am sorry but I don't say that. I say that the product doesn't work according to its documentation which is probably a bug and the best bet is to be resolved by the package developer as it isn't a popular package and there isn't wide knowledge regarding that, and the other good bet is to look for alternatives and I suggested one that works. Anything wrong with that?

Comment: Your comment about just because something is named xxx doesn’t mean that it works is kinda conspiracy theory.  Also, just because something isn’t popular doesn’t mean they should go to GitHub.  There are a ton of stack overflow `tags`s with a low number of questions.   Doesn’t mean no one uses it

Comment: Maybe reword the first paragraph and I’ll be happy to upvote

Comment: OK, I've deleted my last comment as I find that you are right in your last 2 comments, sorry. Also reworded according to this conversation, as said you where right regarding some points but you can also see that my basic intention was to help and the answer had helpful elements. Thanks for pointing out on the flaws.

Comment: Thanks.  Not a problem good sir.  Upvoted.  A downvote is not necessarily permanent especially with guiding comments.   Just giving you a chance to improve it which you did. :)